# python- Pythonic way to lower string in list along with other elements

Tags: python

```
def duplicate(inputList):
    inputList = [inputList for x in inputList if inputList[x] is str]
    print(inputList)


if __name__=='__main__':
    duplicate([1,2,3,2,1,3,"Hello","HeLlo"]);
```

I want to lower all the string and find the duplicates in the inputList

Comment: What have you tried? [so] is not a code writing service.

Comment: What do you mean by *'find the duplicates'*? What result would you expect?

Comment: result should be [1,2,3,"hello"]

Comment: Is the result the unique elements of the original list or what ever elements that have duplicates?

Comment: Should `duplicate([1, 2, 3, 1]) == [1]`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `isinstance` to check the element type:

```
[x.lower() if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in lst]
# [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 'hello', 'hello']
```

Or:

```
[x.lower() if type(x) is str else x for x in lst]
# [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 'hello', 'hello']
```

If you want to find out the unique elements from the list, you can use a set comprehension:

```
{x.lower() if type(x) is str else x for x in lst}
# {1, 2, 3, 'hello'}
```

Or get the duplicates:

```
dupes = []
vals = set()

for x in lst:

    if isinstance(x, str):
        x = x.lower()

    if x in vals:
        dupes.append(x)
    else:
        vals.add(x)  

dupes
# [2, 1, 3, 'hello']
```

Comment: Answers like this are why I've copy-pasted four "we're not a code writing service" comments in the last 2 minutes... because people **are** answering regardless of how little effort the OP put in.

Comment: @PeterWood I didn't see the find duplicates part initially. Thought he just wanted to know how to lower case the strings.

Comment: See [**`unique_everseen`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)